# Unable to comment or flag on main SO site

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, flags

Clicking `add comment` has no effect, and clicking `flag` brings me to the top of the current page but does nothing.  I first noticed it when I followed a notification to someone's comment directed to me, and couldn't comment it. Then I found a post that needed flagging, and I couldn't flag it. Restarted my browser and tried new tabs. Is there something else I can try? *Meta works just fine for commenting/flagging/etc.*

Firefox 20.0.1. Not sure what other information I can give/you need.

Comment: Do you see any errors in Firefox's console? (F12).

Comment: @Matt Didn't even think to check that at the time. Though, I just tried F12 and the console didn't come up; had to open it from the Firefox menu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try clearing your browser's caches etc. Might be a corrupted javascript file in your cache.

The quick way: press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on a SO page. This will hard-refresh and re-fetch every cachable object from the server.

If that did not help, disable plugins first en re-enable them one by one. They sometimes cause weird behaviour.

Comment: This worked after using ctrl+shift+R. Thanks.